# How to compute a selective norm for a Multi-Index DF

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have measurement data in MultiIndex spreadsheet format and need to compute a norm by dividing each value of a column by its corresponding reference value.

How can this be done efficiently and 'readable' using Python Pandas, i.e. how do I filter the correct reference value in order to compute the normed values?

Here's the input data:

```
            result
var     run     ID  
10  1   A   10
        B   50
    2   A   30
        B   70
20  1   A   100
        B   500
    2   A   300
        B   700
30  1   A   1000
        B   5000
    2   A   3000
        B   7000
```

and this is the desired result:

```
            normed
var     run     ID  
10  1   A   0.1
        B   0.1
    2   A   0.1
        B   0.1
20  1   A   1.0
        B   1.0
    2   A   1.0
        B   1.0
30  1   A   10.0
        B   10.0
    2   A   10.0
        B   10.0
```

As can be seen, var = 20 is the reference, but it gets even more complicated since there are two runs (1 and 2) and two devices under test.

I can create a mask `df[df['var' == 20]` when the DF is flattened using df.reset_index() (see comment #1), but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Any help is deeply appreciated!

**Update**

I have found a solution using query() in a for loop:

```
df_norm = pd.DataFrame()
df_flat = df.reset_index()
var_ref = 20
for ident in 'A','B':
    for run in 1,2:
        q = f'var == {var_ref} & run == {run} & ID == "{ident}"'
        ref = df_flat.query(q)
        #ref
        #ref.result
        #ref.result.iloc[0]
        q = f'run == {run} & ID == "{ident}"'
        df_m = df_flat.query(q)
        norm = df_m.result / ref.result.iloc[0]
        #norm
        df__ = pd.DataFrame(norm.rename('norm'))
        df__ = df_flat.merge(df__, left_index=True, right_index=True)
        df_norm = pd.concat([df_norm, df__])

df_norm.sort_index()
```

Maybe there's a more elegant way to do it?